# Where to ask question about SE stats?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, statistics

Can I ask questions about stats (which I personally adore) of Stack Exchange network itself?

For example:

- Which user has the largest number of gold badges, while retaining reputation lower than 1000?
- Which question has the largest number of answers?
- Which answer has the largest number of comments?
- What is a typical page view count for entire network?
- *many more...*

And, if I can, then what would be the best place? Here on meta or maybe on [Stats](http://stats.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want to do is head over to the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

This has all the queries others have run so you might find that what you're looking for is already written. If not you can write your own queries.

The queries can be run on any site, but only one site at a time. This means that to get the question with the largest number of answers across the entire network you'll have to run the query for each site saving the results to your machine and then sort that result set.

You certainly don't want to ask on Cross Validated as that's not what the site is about.