# Where (if anywhere) should I post request for certain Data Explorer's queries?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, statistics

Following [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240812/189165). I'm a complete newbie (or even ignorant) to both SQL and [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). I'm [interested in getting some stats about Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240812/189165), but writing even a simple query seems to me as an overwhelming problem.

Is there any place, where I can politely ask someone to write a particular query for me?

Would that be:

- this meta site,
- particular site's meta,
- somewhere in [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) itself,
- *nowhere* (if I can't write a query myself, then this is my problem and I should not bother others).

I'm asking, because I lost quite a large rep stupidly recently, due to high volume of downvotes and I'd like to avoid similar in future, by not asking wrong questions.

Comment: OK, fine. But... how do you find these two questions duplicate? I'm asking about writing certain queries, and for me "asking about Data Explorer itself" is something completely different. Am I wrong?